# Python Script to check ldap connection from netstat command

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ansible

I have Below python script which works fine, However, i see this can be formulate better way like `if not any(['my-ldap01' in line, 'my-ldap02' in line, 'my-ldapdc01' in line, 'my-ldapdc02' in line]):`  ldap Server names can be assign to a variable?

Please advise if you see there is something better which can be done to this piece of code.

```
#!/grid/common/pkgs/python/v3.6.1/bin/python3
from __future__ import print_function
from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_DFL)
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import os
import time
timestamp = time.strftime('%b-%d-%Y:%H:%M')
#### Collecting LDAP Connection on port 389 with Ansible ad hoc's ##########
def CallAnsible():
    os.chdir('/Karn/inventory')
    os.system('ansible all -m shell -a "netstat -aplt --numeric-ports| grep :389 | grep its | grep ESTABLISHED" -f 200 | tee -a netstat_ldap.logs &')
    time.sleep(180)
CallAnsible()
#### Booleans and Variable declaration For the ease of code ##########
def ldapConn():
    Flag    = False
    FlagTcp = False
    NewStr  = ''
    OutStr  = ''
    OutStr1 = ''
    HOST    = ''
    MARKER  = '----------------'
    NEWLINE = '\n'
    fileData = '/Karn/inventory/netstat_parsed.logs'
    with open('/Karn/inventory/netstat_ldap.logs', 'r') as log:
        for line in log:
            if '>>' in line:
                if HOST != 'NA' and Flag:
                    OutStr = OutStr + NEWLINE + HOST + NEWLINE + MARKER + NEWLINE + NewStr
                    OutStr1 = ''
            if 'SUCCESS' in line:
                Flag = False
                Flagtcp = True
                HOST = line.split()[0]
                NewStr = ''
            elif 'FAILED' in line or 'UNREACHABLE' in line:
                Flagtcp = False
                NewStr = ''
                HOST = 'NA'
            if Flagtcp and line.startswith('tcp'):
                NewStr += line
                if not any(['my-ldap01' in line, 'my-ldap02' in line, 'my-ldapdc01' in line, 'my-ldapdc02' in line]):
                    Flag = True
            if HOST != 'NA' and Flag and HOST not in OutStr:
                OutStr1 = HOST + NEWLINE + MARKER + NEWLINE + NewStr
                DataLog = open(fileData, 'w')
                DataLog.write('{0} {1}'.format(OutStr,OutStr1))
                #DataLog.write(OutStr + ' ' + OutStr1)
        log.close()
        DataLog.close()
ldapConn()
#########################################################################################################
#                       EMAIL NOTIFICATION                                              #
#########################################################################################################
def ps_Mail():
    filename = '/Karn/inventory/netstat_parsed.logs'
    f = open(filename)
    if os.path.exists(filename) and os.path.getsize(filename) > 0:
        mailp = Popen(['/usr/sbin/sendmail', '-t', '-oi'], stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['To'] = 'karn@xyz.com'
        msg['Subject'] = 'Alert! Clients Connecting Outside SJ for ldap Connections.!'
        msg['From'] = 'ldapconnectionInfo@xyz.com'
        msg1 = MIMEText(f.read(),  'text')
        msg.attach(msg1)
        mailp.communicate(msg.as_string())
    else:
        mailp = Popen(['/usr/sbin/sendmail', '-t', '-oi'], stdin=PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['To'] = 'karn@xyz.com'
        msg['Subject'] = 'ALL the LDAP Connections are Healthy,Good Day!'
        msg['From'] = 'ldapconnectionInfo@xyz.com'
        msg1 = MIMEText(f.read(),  'text')
        msg.attach(msg1)
        mailp.communicate(msg.as_string())
ps_Mail()
###### removes the Files after parsing the data#########
os.rename('/Karn/inventory/netstat_ldap.logs', '/Karn/old_ldap_logs/netstat_ldap.logs-' + timestamp)
os.rename('/Karn/inventory/netstat_parsed.logs', '/Karn/old_ldap_logs/netstat_parsed.logs-' + timestamp)
os.system('/usr/bin/pgrep ansible | xargs kill -9')
```

Note: Using ansible to take the data from severe via netstat

appreciate any advice/help on this.

Comment: So many questions...Why are you backgrounding the netstat pipeline with `&` and then calling `time.sleep()`? Why not just remove the `&`, in which case it won't return until it completes? Have you looked at something like [testinfra](https://testinfra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for running the remote command, rather than calling ansible and then parsing information out of logs yourself? Why not use `subprocess` instead of `os.system`, collect the output from ansible yourself, and then parse it in python rather than relying on a long shell pipeline?

Comment: Sorry, this should have been the first question: why are you calling Ansible from Python, rather than doing it the other way around? Start with an Ansible playbook and implement the logic you need there.

Comment: @larsks, thanks for the information, i'll look on the suggested changes but for now it works for me, appreciate your advice it helps, i never used testinfra , surely i'll check this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make a list of the items you want to check for like this, but I don't know if it's much faster/better than what you used already (other than looking neater). (this was written based on my understanding of it from reading. You can change it how you like)

```py
linetest = ["my-ldap01","my-ldap02","my-ldapdc01", "my-ldapdc02"]

if line not in linetest:
    Flag = True
```

Comment: Thanks @Column01 for the answer +1 for this.

Comment: No problem. Hope you can figure it out. Don't hesitate to comment here if you need anymore help :D

Comment: if this answered your question, you should mark it as an answer (which I believe it did)

Comment: Thanks a mile @Column01 .